# Move files to network share, local space is not freed up

Tags: windows, networking

I have seen this many times, over multiple days and many reboots:

- I have 0.5GB free locally
- I move a 2GB folder from local to network share

  - It is gone locally
- Local drive still shows 0.5GB free

To see the 2GB as released I have to reboot (which seems and feels wrong and is definitely a PITA).

Notes:

- I am using Windows File Explorer to move files
- I am using a command prompt dir command to see free space
- This problem happens whether I have 0.5GB free or 20GB free
- I don't think it is background writes, because the NAS I am copying to shows "all quiet" shortly after the move operation completes.

Advised approach to resolve?

Comment: What are you using to view the used disk space? Your question doesn't appear to actually have anything to do with networking, so you may want to remove that tag, unless the behavior is different if you move items to some other form of attached, non-local storage, like a USB drive.

Comment: what kind disk is it (HDD/SSD/other)? do you usually have the volume that full? you may want to avoid situations where you have less than 10% free, depending on the size of the disk, especially if its a system volume.

Comment: What's the speed of your network? It'll be quite a long while to transfer 2GB over the network, so have you waited for a long enough time? As long as the file wasn't fully transferred, space can't be released.

Comment: @music2myear OP enhanced to answer your question. Thank you!

Comment: @harrymc I don't think the raw speed matters. It is what it is. A copy like this takes some time, but happens fully in the foreground. OP enhanced. Thank you!

Comment: Years ago I solved just such a problem. The problem was the antivirus opening deleted files and not letting the delete to finish. Disabling the antivirus solved the problem. The antivirus was then McAfee. I don't know if your problem is the same, but you could try.

Comment: Note that even in the forground, disk write caching is completely transparent to the user, so you won't see it being used in any circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to [write caching](https://www.minitool.com/news/disk-write-caching.html) and network speed limitations. Not all operations finish immediately. Some are batched together, others may **appear** to complete, such as moving a large amount of data to a network drive, but *are still running in the background*. Rather than requiring reboot, it might just take *additional time* to finish.

BTW, it's faster to sign out and back in than to reboot, if you determine that just waiting is insufficient. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>, select *Sign out*, then log in again.

Also, as others mentioned, having just 0.5 GB free is inviting disaster. Even 2.5 GB is cutting too close. 10 GB of free space would be a minimum, IMHO.

Comment: I updated the OP to address the topics you raise.

Answer (score 0):

Your page file grows as space becomes available. You already have too little free space so the page file is struggling to grow and will grab any new space you free up.

When you reboot the page file is recreated (smaller) but will grow as you use the system.